# How can I make a full width div?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, html, asp.net-mvc-4

Even after making the body have no space on the sides, my div is still off-center. I have the div taking up the full width of the screen as I need, but can't get it to be centered. I forced it with margin-left but that didn't work on other screens. Any suggestions?

CSS

```
div {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
body {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

section {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    border: 0px 0px 0px 0px;

}

.div-with-bg {
    background-image: url(../images/color1.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: grey;
    /*this is needed to keep image proportion good*/
    background-size: cover;
    position:relative;
    margin-left:0px;
    border-left:0px;
    padding-left:0px;
}

.div-no-sides {
    /*margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;*/
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    border: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    /*margin-left: -5em;*/
}
```

HTML

```
<section class="hero div-no-sides" style="width:100vw">
    <div class="container div-with-bg div-no-sides wide">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h1>
                Heading Goes Here
            </h1>

            <p class="tagline">
                Quick. Accurate. Reliable.
            </p>
            <a class="btn btn-full" href="#about">Get A Quote Today</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Are you asking how to center a div on a page? Or are you asking how to make a div stretch the fullscreen of a page. Your question is unclear please specify? Also you are using bootstraps grid system, but I see no addition of a link to bootstrap, also your col-md-12 is not wrapped in a row class.

Comment: @BenTegoni My link to bootstrap is in the layout page. I want the div to stretch the fullscreen, but when I use width:100vw it makes the size perfect, but puts it off center to the right and i have to scroll horizontally to see it.

Comment: the result I get when I run the above code is a div that stretches full screen perfectly, there isn't a problem with it. Could you please provide a code snippet that clearly demonstrates your problem (the one that you can actually run) so I can see what you're trying to say properly.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row" style="height:100px; background: #fff;"> this is ok</div>
    <div class="row row-full" style="height:100px; background: #f00;">
        this should take 100% width
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container{
 background: gray;
 min-height: 400px;
}

/*Can achive using vw css unit*/
.row-full{
      width: 100vw;
      position: relative;
      margin-left: -50vw;
      height: 100px;
      margin-top: 100px;
      left: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, using your HTML structure, you could use the following CSS to make the text centered:

```
html,body{
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}

.div-with-bg {
    background-image: url(../images/color1.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: grey;
    /*this is needed to keep image proportion good*/
    background-size: cover;
}

.container div {
text-align:center;
}
```

Technically, to help answer your question, a  will always, natively want to be the full width of any space it occupies, whether it's limited in it's width by a parent node or the body tag of the page. Specifically, because you'd mentioned that you wanted your text centered, you'd include that in a lower-level CSS div declaration.

Answer (score 0):

I moved my code from my Index page to my layout page and then it started working as intended. I believe that having an @Renderbody in the layout page that was displaying on the index page is what was causing my issue.